# Como enviar datos de un Handle de una Actividad hacia un Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

actualmente estoy adquiriendo valores empleando la clase MyHandler que pertenece al MainActivity y se visualizan perfecto en un TextView, pero ahora necesito visualizar la misma información en un fragment, creo que una opción es crear un bundle en el onCreateView del fragment, pero no se como hacer para que escuche los datos que entran todo el tiempo.

Este es el **MainActivity** donde la información que necesito pertenece a la variable line y que actualmente se muestra en un TextView llamado display.

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler {
        public final WeakReference<MainActivity> mActivity;
        public MyHandler(MainActivity activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

@Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case UsbService.MESSAGE_FROM_SERIAL_PORT:
                    line = (String) msg.obj;
                    mActivity.get().display.append(line);
                case UsbService.CTS_CHANGE:
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity.get(), "CTS_CHANGE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case UsbService.DSR_CHANGE:
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity.get(), "DSR_CHANGE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
 }
```

Ahora en mi **fragment** defino un nuevo display para llevar llevar la información allí

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    public TextView newdisplay;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        newdisplay = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.newdisp);



        return root;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Ya probaste mandarla con un Intent?

Comment: Hola Franco, esto intentado así; 
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
Bundle a = new Bundle();
a.putString("keyline", line);`
intent.putExtra("pass", a);
startActivity(intent);   Pero no se como recibirlo en el fragment

Comment: Tu quieres enviar la información a tu fragment o tu mainactivity? Porque ese intent lo deja en tu main activity

Comment: Quiero enviar la informacion al fragment

Comment: Vale, he añadido una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Primero, haremos el `Intent` para mandarlo al `Fragment`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TuFragment.class); 
Bundle a = new Bundle(); 
a.putString("keyline", line);` 
intent.putExtra("pass", a); startActivity(intent);
```

Ahora, en tu `Fragment` declararemos una variable:

```
private Bundle b = null;
```

Luego, lo agregas en donde sea que lo necesites:

```
b = getIntent().getStringExtra("pass");
```

Prueba depurando esta línea `b = getIntent().getStringExtra("pass");` para ver si te trae el valor que quieres mostrar.

Comment: Hola Franqo, lo realicé como indicas, mas sin embargo fue necesario cambiar el bundle de la siguiente manera para que no genere error, private String b = null; y considero que lo que me indicas es correcto, pero finalmente no se carga en el TextView, no crees que se pueda hacer de otra forma que siempre se quede escuchando? por ejemplo cuando se pone un botón a escuchar con un setOnClickListener?

Comment: Buenas, ¿No se te carga el `TextView`? Probaste quitando esta línea: a.putString("keyline", line);` y haciendo esto: `intent.putExtra("pass", line);`. Debugea esta línea final para ver si capta el dato y te lo muestra. Si sale error porque los datos son distitntos prueba añadiendo `intent.putExtra("pass", String.valueOf(line));` Y en respuesta a tu última pregunta, puedes hacerlo con un botón :)